# A spot on the lens inside the camera

Tags: lens, optics, old-cameras, spots

[image]

[image]

Hello! Is there someone who has experience with this kind of "spot-on-the-lens" stuff? :)

I bought a used 35 mm camera and discovered a "spot" on the lens inside. Of course, it doesn't help to clean the lens. Haven't tested shooting with it yet. Just wondering, is it something with the coating, or is it fungus? Will it affect the image?

Comment: This doesn't really change the answer(s) much, but out of curiosity, is this a fixed-lens 35mm, or is it a camera with interchangeable lenses?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like fungus to me. You can try to clean it off but it may well have affected the coating and/or etched the glass.

It looks like it's in the dead center of the rear element so it may affect contrast and/or image sharpness, perhaps more noticeably at small apertures.

Run a roll through it and take shots at various apertures and lighting situations. That's really the only way to tell whether the camera/lens will be acceptable to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: What are the odds that said fungus is going to contaminate other lenses used in the same camera?

Comment: @xenoid I was wondering if the camera is a SLR, or a fixed-lens 35mm.

Comment: Ah, yes. Fixed lens. Forgot about those :)

Comment: My first impression is that this looks like a fixed lens compact 35mm film camera,